How to exclude folders already excluded in attached modules?
I have a project called app_gallery
I attached a module called shared_frontend. As you can see, I had to manually exclude the folders dumdum and linux.

However, if I open the project shared_frontend as a standalone project, build, ios, linux, macos .. are already excluded.

Because those folders are already marked as excluded in .idea/shared_frontend.iml
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/macos" />
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/web" />
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/windows" />
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.fvm" />

But why do I have to manually re-exclude all of them one by one again when I attached this project as module to my main project app_gallery ?
Is there a way to make Jetbrain exclude those automatically ?
